# Can a MapServer datasource be a materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, mapserver, data-source

I'd like to find out if there is a way that a datasource in MapServer can be a materialized view, this is due to the presence of indexes, these cannot be in views but only in materialized view - however, I seem to have trouble having MapServer accept materialized view as a datasource.

Comment: What kind of index would you need? If table has a spatial index it should work transparently also for simple views created like `select geometry, attr from table where ...`. Materialized views should work as well. You must give more details about what you've done and what fails.

Comment: I have MapServer working against a standard view on PostgreSQL 9.2 to give WMS and WFS so I'm guessing the answer here should be yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mapserver works with materialized view, configuration should be provided like for a simple Postgis relation.
Example of layer configuration can be found in documentation:

https://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html